# When you do not use foreign keys between tables how else do you then express a relationship

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, parent-child

I have 2 tables. A Parent and Children table. When I delete parent records they should not delete the children records. Thus I do not use ON Delete cascade. And I also do not want to use Foreign keys at all because then I can not delete the parent record if there is still a children record referenced. Make the FKey nullable to have an optional relation is no option either because the a children can only exist if there is a related parent.

OK FKey totally removed. In my Entity relationship diagram there is no relationship between those 2 tables. But that is not true. This could be misleading when I look 6 months later at the diagram.

What would you do now?

Comment: This->"When I delete parent records they should not delete the children records." seems to contradict "Make the FKey nullable to have an optional relation is no option either because the a children can only exist if there is a related parent."  One or the other can be true, but not both.

Comment: Hm.. well there should be NO Delete-relation but there should be obviously visible a Get-data-relation like get all children for a certain parent. In that context I do not need foreign keys. But without foreign keys I can not express a relation at all in a diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to sometimes delete parent rows (not just flag them) without deleting child rows, it looks to me like you have two options.

1. NULL the parent's key in the child table when you delete the parent rows.
2. Keep the parent's key in the child table when you delete the parent rows.

In the first case, use a foreign key and `ON DELETE SET NULL` to do that. (Assuming your dbms supports that constraint.)

In the second case, use no foreign key constraint.

Your requirement for a non-nullable foreign key doesn't make sense. On the one hand, you say the children can exist only if there is a related parent. On the other hand, you want to delete the parent without deleting the children. Those two requirements won't play well together.

Comment: yes they dont play well together BUT these are my requirements. Concrete: 1 Release has N Testplan. When someone is stupid enough to delete a release record not all testplans should be deleted for this release because of reporting/statistics etc...

Comment: ok I think to express a relation I use the FK and make it nullable to prevent the FK constraint. I don`t like the IsActive that much from HLGEM. Does not fit in my design and more work ;-)

Comment: If deleting a release record is stupid, the Right Thing is to revoke delete permissions on that table.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice to delete a parent record if a child record exists. You might consider if it might be better to use an is_Active flag to soft delte instead and maintain data integrity by leaving the record there for reporting of historical information.

Comment: I delete the parent but the child should remain yes for reporting/observation issues. Why should an IsActive field in the child table make it better? I still do not see the real life connection of both tables after 6 months when there is no foreign key.

Comment: IS active in the parent. Other wise you lose the data in the parent table (So you know customer 12345 ordered stuff on May 13, 2011 but have no way to tell who customer id 12345 is) and either have to denormalize (and possibly keep up changes with a trigger or not depending on how historical the information is) or do a soft delete.  For instance suppose you delte a customer who had an order. The item they ordered later got recalled for a life threatening problem. Is it aporblme that you don't know who ordered it?

Comment: In that life threatening context it should be forbidden actually to ever delete a customer ;-)

Comment: Even If I would do this soft deletion by "deactivate" the deleted parent record. Where is the relation in my diagram visible?

Comment: YOu still have to formally create the foreign key constraint

Comment: ok do the fk formally and set the IsActive of the parent to false/0. I must sleep about that. Thanks.